# Dynamically Pass -D parameter tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I am starting Tomcat using startup.sh , I need to get below two parameters in my rest application deployed in Tomcat.

- logfileLoc
- debugLevel

I read through some of the information on stack overflow, it says you can configure it as below.

```
CATALINA_OPTS="${CATALINA_OPTS} -DlogfileLoc=value -DdebugLevel=value2"
```

But I don't want to hard code the values, it should be taken from the user who starts the Tomcat. so is it possible to send these parameters during startup?

Answer (score 0):

How about running the command before the user start Tomcat using startup.sh?

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -DlogfileLoc=value -DdebugLevel=value2"
```

Comment: will try it and post my findings.